# Performing ETL Actions via sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, etl

I am looking into replacing our current ETL Datawarehouse Program with a set of scripts that use sqlplus to complete the ETL actions. Loading and extracting are simple enough via spooling files and sqlldr +loader files. Is there an industry standard, or Oracle backed solution that I am just not finding?

Comment: there's a whole industry built around ETL processing. Depending on the scale of the data and other requirements, you can 1. roll your own, 2. buy a vendor package, Informatica, Datastage, Ab Initio, and others (at a significant price tag), 3. experiment with an open-source no-sql loader (hadoop maybe). Good luck.

Comment: But if you were looking to do it via sqlplus command line interface, how would it be best done?

Comment: sqlldr is the way I would go as it the Oracle supported tool, provides plenty (too many!) options and you'll find many pieces to the sqlldr puzzle here on S.O. The other solution I've seen in the roll-your-own is to use java, python or other language coupled with `odbc` like drivers to load data. The `sqlldr` process can be managed pretty well with library of shell scripts. Good luck.

Comment: I have also seen use of External Tables as a complement to/extension of SQL*Loader.

Comment: For transforms that take place during an extract, would you recommend calling sqlplus twice, once for the transform and then again for the spool or together?

Comment: It would help to have some sense of 'bigger than a bread-box, smaller than a house' scale of your project. But in cases I'm familiar with, 1. either 3rd parties deliver data via sftp etc (given security today, a whole headache in itself) OR you 'E'xtract data from a 2ndary DB in your organization using sqlplus (or isql, etc). 2. You can 'T'ransform data in the query, or you can run a separate process on that output to transform it (awk or perl or other, depending on the complexity). 3. 'L'oad text data from step 2, into a staging table using sqllr.

Comment: 4. you'll need to migrate the data from the text defined staging table into the final tables (with proper types for numbers, dates, etc) . A select into may be all you need, or a stored proc, or some PL SQL, again depending on the complexity and the required transformations. Good luck.